# Show/hide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little blog with some social buttons for sharing that are integrated into my theme.

Now I want to change show/hide so that it is shown by default and hidden when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post-share").hide();
    $("a.share-btn").click(function() {
        $(this).prev(".post-share").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So what problem are you having? What's your HTML?

Comment: Need to see some html...

Comment: me too, I didn't see his problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `hide` to `show` in dom ready

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post-share").show();
    $("a.share-btn").click(function() {
       $(this).prev(".post-share").slideToggle("slow");
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".post-share").show();
  $("a.share-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).prev(".post-share").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to show by default and then hide when clicked...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post-share").show();
    $("a.share-btn").click(function() {
        $(this).prev(".post-share").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```